# symfony2 recompile container from controller

Tags: symfony, controller, containers, recompile

I want to recompile container from controller when I use `$this->container->compile();`

```
public function changeAction(Request $request)
{
    //......
    echo($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user')."\n");
    /*$cmd='php ../app/console cache:clear';
    $process=new Process($cmd);
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if ('err' === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        }
        else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
    });*/

    $this->container->compile();
    echo($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user')."\n");
    die();
}
```

I got an error : You cannot compile a dumped frozen container

I want to know if when I clear the cache from controller the container will recompile?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get values of parameters that have been modified during request, you can do this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderResolver;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\PhpFileLoader;

public function changeAction(Request $request)
{
    $originalParam = $this->container->getParameter('mailer_user');

    // Rebuild the container
    $container = new ContainerBuilder();    
    $fileLocator = new FileLocator($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/config');

    // Load the changed config file(s)
    $loader = new PhpFileLoader($container, $fileLocator);
    $loader->setResolver(new LoaderResolver([$loader]));
    $loader->load('parameters.php'); // The file that loads your parameters

    // Get the changed parameter value
    $changedParam = $container->get('mailer_user');

    // Or reset the whole container
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Also, if you need to clear the cache from a controller, there is a cleaner way:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput(
    ['command' => 'cache:clear']
));
```

Comment: my parameters are stored in database

Comment: And so ? Do you need that I adapt the example for a `parameters.php` file ?

Comment: I read here that when the cache is cleared the container is rebuild 

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey-di/symfony-builds-the-container

Comment: if you can me give me en example for a parameters.php why not ^^

Comment: Of course if you clear the cache the container is rebuilt, but I suspect that if the parameter has changed during request, even if you clear the cache, you'll get the old value (not the one of the new container build, because the container instance is still the same in your controller).

Comment: I just try to give you exactly what you need, I'll adapt my answer to your use case, I tell you when it's done.

Comment: thank you chalasr 
the seconde $this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'); it just for testing if my parameter has changed or not. i don't need it.
i have trying with another controller and it work perfectly, this is what I want already

Comment: Glad to help @AhmedGhaziKsibi , don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: it is done :)
juste 
there is difference with that ?

$cmd='php ../app/console cache:clear';
    $process=new Process($cmd);
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if ('err' === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        }
        else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
    });

Comment: The result will be the same, only the way is different, maybe more adapted to be used from browser because you can use different kind of Input/Output and some other stuffs. I don't know why but I believed that you are using using an `exec('php app/console cache:clear')`, not the Process component which is also perfectly adapted.

Answer (score 0):

In short the answer is no, the container will not be recompiled, because it is already loaded into memory, and deleting files from disk will take no effect on current request. And on the next request cache will be warmed up and container will be compiled before you reach the controller.